# Resolving an area of a polygon with sides known

Tags: polygons

If I have a polygon with the sides given, is it able to calculate the area of it?
If yes, how many sides do I need to know at least?

A formula is appreciated.

I know how to get the area with a triangle.

$$
\sqrt[2]{(\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)\frac{1}{2}(-a+b+c)\frac{1}{2}(a-b+c)\frac{1}{2}(a+b-c)}
$$

And I have somehow figured out a way for a trapezoid by splitting the area into two parts - a triangle consisting of two right triangles and a rectangle (area = smaller parallel side times height).

$$
\frac{(b+d)}{4(b-d)}\sqrt[2]{(a+b+c-d)(-a+b+c-d)(a+b-c-d)(-a-b+c+d)}
$$

Where b and d are parallel sides.

Maybe it can be achieved by splitting the polygon into (total number of sides - 2) triangles.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area_and_centroid).

Comment: That's interesting. I never thought there was such a way to figure it out with its perimeter.

Answer (score 3):

If only the lengths of the sides are known, the answer is no for more than three sides. Eg a square can be squashed to make an increasingly thin rhombus with the same side length and vanishingly small area. Unless a figure is rigid, you need more than the lengths of the sides to determine the area.

Comment: Good example. By 'more than...' you mean angles, or other elements?